# how do I compare current date with date which is entered by the user?

Tags: java, oracle11g

I want to compare current date with date which is entered by the user.
In my form I have fields as

```
Name:
TicketNO:
ContactNo:
Issue Date: 13/4/2013
Return Date: 17/4/2013
```

The above data is collected from user and entered into database and I want to compare issue date with the system date and on return date i want to send mail to user that your Return date is today.

The database is Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the basic date comparion between current date and input date given by the user right?
Do it like this:

```
Calendar userDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
userDate.setTime(inputDate);//here inputDate is date given by the user.

if(!userDate.before(currentDate)) {
    // user date is after current date(today).
} else {
    // user date is before current date(today).
}
```

Comment: This would not work if the `issued_date` was say at 2 PM and the current time is 1 PM (when the program runs). You're better off just checking the day.